How to get durable function runtime status, using .net 8 isolated worker
var runtimeStatus = new List<OrchestrationRuntimeStatus>
{
  OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running
};
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = source.Token;
var statuses = await starter.ListInstancesAsync(new OrchestrationStatusQueryCondition()
{
 RuntimeStatus = runtimeStatus
}, new CancellationToken());

This code is not compatible with isolated worker. How do I change it?


How to get durable function runtime status, using .net 8 isolated worker


The dotnet isolated model and in-process model have different packages.
In Isolated worker model must have the below packages.

.cs proj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

By using these packages can be get the orchestration runtime status.

In the isolated worker approach can be interact with the Durable Functions runtime using the DurableClient class instead of OrchestrationClient.

Code:
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Function
{
    private readonly IDurableClient durableClient;

    public Function(IDurableClient durableClient)
    {
        this.durableClient = durableClient;
    }

    public async Task<List<DurableOrchestrationStatus>> GetOrchestrationStatus()
    {
        OrchestrationStatusQueryCondition queryCondition = new OrchestrationStatusQueryCondition()
        {
            RuntimeStatus = new[] { OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running }
        };

        return await durableClient.ListInstancesAsync(queryCondition, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}


The package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask must be installed.
IDurableClient is injected into function class constructor. You can achieve this using dependency injection with Azure Functions isolated worker.


Hi Pavan thank you. I didn't realise that webjobs is still used when 'worker isolated'

Theire is actually an issue in the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask version 1.1.2. The serializationInput is empty. If you need to use it, you can downgrade to the version 1.0.4 : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/2693

I'm not sure how this answer has been accepted given that Microsoft's own advice (emphasis theirs!) is: "Your isolated worker model application should not reference any packages in the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs. namespaces or Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions*. If you have any remaining references to these, they should be removed. "

Below sample using latest durable package and not using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask. Hope this helps.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Below uses GetAsyncEnumerator() and MoveNextAsync() since GetAllInstancesAsync() returning AsyncPageable. This function will return the instance Id and the runtime status.
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Sievo.InfoHub.EcoVadis.Lib.Persistence;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class Function
    {
        [Function(nameof(Orchestrator))]
        public async Task Orchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            // Your orchestration code

            // sample get status code
            var statuses = await context.CallActivityAsync<Dictionary<string, OrchestrationRuntimeStatus>>(nameof(GetStatus));
            foreach (var status in statuses)
            {
                if (status.Value == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Pending)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            }

        }

        [Function(nameof(GetStatus))]
        public async Task<Dictionary<string, OrchestrationRuntimeStatus>> GetStatus(
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient starter)
        {
            var queryFilter = new OrchestrationQuery
            {
                Statuses = new[]
                {
                    OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Pending,
                    OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running,
                },
                PageSize = 100,
            };

            var instances = starter.GetAllInstancesAsync(queryFilter);
            var instanceEnumerator = instances.GetAsyncEnumerator();

            var statuses = new Dictionary<string, OrchestrationRuntimeStatus>();
            while (await instanceEnumerator.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var instance = instanceEnumerator.Current;
                statuses.Add(instance.InstanceId, instance.RuntimeStatus);
            };

            return statuses;
        }
    }
}


Hi @Umecks, good point regarding webjobs, it is not used in isolated worker model
